# Checking for correlations when dataset contains numeric and categorical feats?

Tags: python, statistics, correlation, statistical-test

I've got a dataset with 50 features, so visualisation is out of the question. Aiming instead to get a list or table showing the pairs of variables that are correlated and which are statistically significant.

Am I supposed to manually loop thorugh all of the different combinations, applying chi2 (for cat-cat), pearson(for num-num) and point-biserial (for num-cat). Then for each, calculate the correlation coefficient and the p-value? Whilst possible, that will take someone of my skill level quite a bit of time to do.

Is there a more efficient coding solution to handle this situation?

I tried Phik which is supposed to handle this situation but some of the significance scores are negative numbers, which is raising alarm bells.

Comment: Factorizing your numerical values will allow numerical correlation testing and will make things more convenient.